# Xcode 7 - SVN commit failed error - what do do?

Tags: ios, svn, xcode7

I am getting the following error from xcode/source control/Commit

[image]

I don't even see the file in my xcode project. is not there.

When I tried to add the unversioned file via terminal, the response was like the following

```
PJs-MacBook-Pro:~ pj$ cd /Users/pj/Desktop/Projects/PGA/WorkingCopies/trunk/CustomerApp/PGAC/
PJs-MacBook-Pro:PGAC pj$ svn add ViewController.h
svn: warning: W155010: '/Users/pj/Desktop/Projects/PGA/WorkingCopies/trunk/CustomerApp/PGAC/ViewController.h' not found
svn: E200009: Could not add all targets because some targets don't exist
svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested operation
```

I can't see the file "ViewController.h" in my project directory. How can I add it ?

Comment: Can you send us the results of "svn st" and "svn st -u"?

Comment: same problem here ... I checked out a new copy of the project multiple times but to no avail ... i face this problem only with image files regardless whether they are in asset catalog or not.

Comment: @JAHelia : you can also use "SVNX". have a look at my another answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another workaround would be to use "SVNX" [Download Link](https://code.google.com/p/svnx/)

it has all the feature and its vary easy to use.

you can get help setting it up with videos on youtube [check out this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSbGF3_8mMg)

Answer (score 2):

Well..

i don't know what was wrong.

but when i tried importing again and then checking out the repo. it started working

Answer (score 0):

the solution that worked for me is to use `Terminal` to commit image files. First `cd` to `image.xcassets` directory, then type `svn commit -m "any commit message"`

Answer (score 0):

Hi need to add root folders to svn:

```
PJs-MacBook-Pro:~ pj$ cd /Users/pj/Desktop/Projects/PGA/WorkingCopies/trunk/CustomerApp/
PJs-MacBook-Pro:PGAC pj$ svn add PGAC
PJs-MacBook-Pro:PGAC pj$ cd PGAC
PJs-MacBook-Pro:PGAC pj$ svn add ViewController.h
```